# Writing data to Firebase using Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Please help. I've been trying for days, watched countless tutorials, and tried different combination of methods on Firebase documentations, but nothing seemed to work.

I'm building a Vue chat project and trying to write data into firebase databases. The code in my `firebase/init.js` is as follows:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;
```

The code in my CreateMessage.vue file is as follows:

```html
<script>
import {collection, addDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
export default {
    name: 'CreateMessage',
    props: ['name'],
    data() {
        return {
            newMessage: null,
            errorText: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createMessage () {
            if (this.newMessage != "") {
                addDoc(collection(firestore, "messages"),{
                    message: this.newMessage,
                    name: this.name,
                    timestamp: Date.now()
                });
                this.newMessage = null;
                this.errorText = null;
            } else {
                this.errorText = "A message must be entered first!";
            }
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: The import db statement is missing in your Component CreateMessage. Also, could you please mention explicitly any errors that you are getting or what is the difficulty you are getting in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you are exporting from your init.js file is db.  And you never import db into your component.  Should import like this

`import { db } from 'firebase/init.js`

and then add the doc...

```
addDoc(collection(db, 'messages'), ...
```

Alternatively, you don't have to import db.  You could just also import getFirestore from firebase/firestore and just do...

```
addDoc(collection(getFirestore(), 'messages'), ...
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much